# Стоит ли учить RxJava и Java 8 если я перешел на Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, работа

Вопрос такой. Я Android разработчик, пишу на котлине. Нужно ли мне учить Java 8 и RxJava, если это указано в требованиях к знаниям в вакансии? По сути в котлине свои фичи, как в Java 8.. Или я что-то не понимаю? Возьмут ли меня если сказать при устройстве что я вместо Java 8 знаю котлин?

Comment: Я не силен в котлине, но есть ли там какая то альтернатива стримам(Stream) и лямбдам? По-моему - нет, потому как котлин последний перенимает все фишки новых джав!)

Comment: > "Можно ли будет сказать при устройстве что я вместо Java 8 знаю котлин?" - Сказать можно, а вот примут вас после этого на работу или нет - неизвестно :)

Comment: про стримы не пробовал, но лямбды вот такие `btn.setOnClickListener { }`

Comment: если в требованиях есть, то знать надо. Если в той коноторе не разрабатывают на котлин, то ваше умение в котлин не оценят, а за не знание rx  и 8 - припомнят. Другое дело, что java 8 в андроид - послезавтрашний день, не знаю, зачем им это сейчас, а реактивное программирование сейчас модно среди андроид девелоперов, знать стоит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все необходимые для Android разработки фишки Java 8 в Котлине есть и отлично поддерживаются. `Stream` из Java 8 вообще ниразу не видел чтобы хоть кто-то из андроид разработчиков применял. Объясняется это, скорее всего, тем, что Java 8 вошла в обиход совсем недавно. Ну и насколько помню по перфомансу `Stream` выигрывают только на больших объемах данных. В остальных случаях обычные коллекции отлично себя показывают. В андроиде в большинстве случаев, если вы работаете с большимы объемами данных, то применяется пагинация.

Стоит ли учить Java 8? Ну, вам надо знать в общих чертах, о чем она. Углубившись в Kotlin вы незаметно и с Java 8 освоитесь).

RxJava вам по любому придется учить, т.к. RxKotlin это просто расширение для RxJava с крутым набором Kotlin extensions. Не более.

P.S. Если в вакансии указано, что надо знать Java, то скорее всего писать будете на ней.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от уровня вашего погружения. Поскольку значительная часть функциональности котлин построена поверх функциональности Java — при ноубоком погружении неплохо бы знать как оно там в джаве работает. Rx — вообще парадигма, независимая от языка, её надо изучать если он вам нужна.